# Reducing the space between components of UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uipickerview

I want to reduce the space between the different components in a UIPickerView. Actually i want to build a picker view similar to the `Timer` in `Watch` app in iPhone.

i believe there are 4 components. First the `hours` component `(0,1,2....23)`, the second one was `hour` component, third one was `minutes` `(0,1,2....59)` and fourth is `min` component. How i can increase the comparative space between `Hour` and `Minute` Components. I don't want to use hour and min word with every hour value and every min value.

Comment: `pickerView:widthForComponent:` from `UIPickerViewDelegate`?

Comment: i want to set the space between the different components not the width of an individual component. This method sets the width of individual component in the picker view.

Answer (score 25):

you would have to use the widthForComponent delegate method. the following is an example for Swift. just find the objective-c equivalent.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30.0
}
```